# C# Read StreamReader Webpage Uri Relative

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, uri, relative-path, streamreader

I got to Download the read the content of this webpage i am using this code
it is for a windows phone app

```
string html = new StreamReader(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("http://www.knbsb.nl/nw/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=382&Itemid=150&lang=nl&LevelID=120&CompID=1580", UriKind.Relative)).Stream).ReadToEnd();
```

I know that the UriKind is set Relative, but it has to be for the other script.

So basically i have to make the webpage to a relative Urikind from a absolute Uri.
But I don't know how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the request asynchronously.
You can use something like this as a helper:

```
public static void RequestAsync(Uri url, Action<string, Exception> callback)
{
    if (callback == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
    }

    try
    {
        var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

        AsyncCallback getTheResponse = ar =>
        {
            try
            {
                string responseString;

                var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

                using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar))
                {
                    using (var streamResponse = resp.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
                        {
                            responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

                callback(responseString, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                callback(null, ex);
            }
        };

        req.BeginGetResponse(getTheResponse, req);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        callback(null, ex);
    }
}
```

You can then make calls like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RequestAsync(
        new Uri("http://www.knbsb.nl/nw/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=382&Itemid=150&lang=nl&LevelID=120&CompID=1580"),
        (html, exc) =>
            {
                if (exc == null)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(html));
                }
                else
                {
                    // handle exception appropriately
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: this is what seems to work because the downloadstring doesn't work for the phones. but i want to assasing the htlm string to this :////////   m_doc = new HtmlDocument(); /////////////
   m_doc.LoadHtml(html);//////// but i can't?

Comment: @Lark125 where are you getting a HtmlDocument class from? The phone doesn't include one as part of the platform SDK. What are you ultimately trying to achieve? You may also want to look at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: i am getting it from htmlagility pack but there they can´t load a absolute path as webadress

Comment: @Lark125 so what happens if you try and call `.LoadHtml(html)` where I'm calling `MessageBox.Show` above?

Comment: so you mean Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=> m_doc.LoadHtml(html) ?

Comment: @Lark125 yes, but you probably don't need to dispatch it back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to do it.

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.youtsite.com");
//do whatever you want with the string. 

    }
```

Comment: WebClient is suboptimal on the phone because it mostly runs on the UIThread.

Comment: DownloadString is not available on the phone. Only the Async version

Answer (score 0):

The `Application.GetResourceStream` is for reading resources from the application package, not for requesting resources from the web.

Use the `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` classes instead.

Example:

```
string html;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
  html = client.DownloadString("http://www.knbsb.nl/nw/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=382&Itemid=150&lang=nl&LevelID=120&CompID=1580");
}
```

Comment: The synchronous methods of WebClient are not available on WP7. Also, WebClient is recommended against in 7.0 due to it always returning on the UI thread.